# Showing multiple lines within textarea after using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to protect against sql injections by using mysql_real_escape_string before inserting data to the database:

```
$data=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);
```

Now, the data is stored as such:

```
That\\\'s an apostrophe.\r\n\r\nThis new line isn\\\'t displaying properly!
```

So, I am trying to get it to display correctly inside of a textarea after pulling it back out of mysql:

```
$data = nl2br($data);
```

For whatever reason, this does NOTHING. I've even tried `str_replace` to replace the `\r\n'`s with a `<br>`, but then the `<br>` just displays within the textarea.

How do I get what's in my mysql to display as:

```
That's an apostrophe.

This new line isn't displaying properly!
```

Comment: Verify your code. It appears you are escaping that string multiple times. The output from `mysql_real_escape_strin` should be: `That\'s an apostrophe. This new line isn\'t displaying properly!`. Which would come out properly.

Comment: be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete and insecure (even if you are escaping properly). They are also being deprecated, which means that they may be removed from PHP in a future version. It is recommended to switch to the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have magic_quotes turned on,
check it with
echo get_magic_quotes_gpc()
or else you will double quote

"Sets the magic_quotes state for GPC (Get/Post/Cookie) operations. When magic_quotes are on, all ' (single-quote), " (double quote), \ (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with a backslash automatically. "

by the way, it's not a good ideia to use magic_quotes, try using one of this classes.

PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
or mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2):

The Best Solution..

`$data= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);` (You can insert it in your database if you want)

`echo stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n',PHP_EOL,$data));` (The output is exactly as your input was)

Answer (score 1):

Actually using `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't fully protect you from `SQL Injection` attack.

- *See here* [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/5741264#5741264)

The best way to do is to use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

- *See here*  [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)